# Questions about the test manager 2012

Tags: testing, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm doing tests with the test manager 2012 on windows 7 and when road testing where it will be tested over a browser test manager I am not able to run the script already written, it does not appear the option to change the browser.

How to enable the function for changing the browser test manager in 2012 while running the test?

Answer (score 1):

The browser *Test Hub* for TFS 2012 does not use data and diagnostic collectors. Hence, you will not be able to playback any previous action recordings.